# MySQL LEFT JOIN Count column Join 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have 3 tables which are part of my database.

```
debates (id 'PK', unit_id, starter_pack_id 'FK', title)

debate_stakeholders (id 'PK', starter_pack_id 'FK', name)

debate_groups (id 'PK', debate_id 'FK', student_id, stakeholder_id 'FK')
```

For this purpose all debates share the same stakeholders (4 stakeholders in total, all of these stakeholders are referenced for all debates).

The aim of my expected outcome to query all the debates, that shows the `debates.id, debates.title, debate_stakeholders.name, and the Count of how many of those stakeholders occur within that particular debate`, **in relation to the relative stakeholder irrespective if the count of stakeholders is 0**. This part is important as when I perform additional queries, I need to know which query counts are greater than or equal to one, zero and null.

Here is the sample data of my database:

[image]

My expected outcome: (The count is just to show what It could look like)

[image]

I have attempted to create this MySQL query, but I am unable to achieve my exact requirements.

I have tried queries such as 
`SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.name, 
    a.abbreviation, 
    d.id AS debateId, 
    IF(COUNT(b.stakeholder_id) = 0, 0, COUNT(b.stakeholder_id)) AS total_freq 
FROM 
    debate_stakeholders a LEFT JOIN debate_groups b ON b.stakeholder_id = a.id 
    LEFT JOIN debates as d ON b.debate_id = d.id
GROUP BY
    a.id, b.debate_id,d.id
HAVING

    COUNT(*) < 3
ORDER BY a.id,d.id
LIMIT 1`

But that hasen't quite planned out.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You should include this, and some sample data would be even better.

Comment: So the debates table has two unique keys? `id` and also `starter_pack_id`? Why is this?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Why are records being filtered off in a `LEFT JOIN`?  Have a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d547/1).

Comment: because debates.starter_pack_id is a foreign key from another table, but it is irrelevant for this solution. In fact I should not have included it. I will remove it

Comment: Ah, okay. You marked it as 'PK'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit that the table names confuse me. A **debate**__stakeholder is not related to a debate. It's rather a stakeholder belonging to a starter pack and there are also debates belonging to a starter pack. At least this is what I read from the table structures. Then a debate_**group** consists of a single student plus a stakeholder in a debate. It is strange to call this a group.

However, it seems you want to combine all stakeholders with all debates in a starter pack (i.e. get all combinations). Then you want to count how many students are related to each such debate / stakeholder combination. So write a query to count students per debate and stakeholder (an aggregation query grouped by debate and stakeholder) and use this as a subquery you outer-join to the debate / stakeholder combinations.

```
SELECT d.id,
       d.title,
       ds.name,
       COALESCE(dg.students, 0) AS "count"
FROM debates d
JOIN debate_stakeholders ds
    ON ds.starter_pack_id = d.starter_pack_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT debate_id, stakeholder_id, COUNT(*) AS students
    FROM debate_groups
    GROUP BY debate_id, stakeholder_id
) dg
    ON dg.debate_id = d.id AND
       dg.stakeholder_id = ds.id;
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: You are champion. This seems to accomplish what I am trying to achieve. Thanks man

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Thank you.

Comment: Could one addtion be made?. What if I want to use that exact, but to show only records where the count is less than '3' or instance?, but still show the other null or 0 count records

Comment: Add `WHERE COALESCE(dg.students, 0) < 3` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this will help:

```
SELECT d.id, COALESCE(d.title, 'NA') AS title, COALESCE(ds.name, 'NA') AS name, COUNT(ds.id) AS count
FROM debates d
LEFT JOIN debate_groups AS dg ON d.id = dg.debate_id
LEFT JOIN debate_stakeholders AS ds ON dg.stakeholder_id = ds.id
GROUP BY d.id, dg.stakeholder_id
```

Comment: Nope.  You filtered off some of the moderators.  The OP wants every moderator to appear for each debate.

Comment: I more so want every stakeholder, to appear for every debate, irrespective if there count is 0